# ImageView problems, image not displaying or throwing error

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview

I am currently trying to place a background image on the login screen of my app. I can't get the image to show up.

1st method tried:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_bg"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_bg" />
```

This opens the app but just doesn't show the image. (It shows a white background instead).

2nd method tried:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/login_bg"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_bg" />
```

Which returns the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: package, PID: 30016
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
```

Full stack trace [here](https://pastebin.com/2x1ZQSYy).

I am extending `Activity` in my LoginActivity.

**EDIT**

I just tried another image and it worked fine. Why is [this](https://www.pexels.com/photo/adventure-alpine-altitude-austria-355241/) particular image not working?

My folder structure:

[image: My folder structure]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your project structure by expanding res folder and inside folders as well

Comment: Does the ImageView cover the whole activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no problem with your XML :

```
android:src="@drawable/login_bg"
```

the problem may be with your image **login_bg**

try a different image in this place **login_bg**, if it works then your image may be the problem, so try to use a different image.

```
android:src="@drawable/new_image"
```

**updated answer**

so, after checking your edited question :

i think you are using a high-resolution image into your app, it was having an 
**OutOfMemoryError** error in your log file.

so you should define `android:largeHeap` and `android:hardwareAccelerated` in your manifest like this:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
....
....
```

hope my answer helps you.

Comment: so if another image works fine, then this image may have some more memory? or the irregular format may be the factors that are affecting it , check out that

Comment: You are a legend my friend! Thanks